# Java: pre-,postfix operator precedences

Tags: java, operator-precedence, post-increment, pre-increment

I have two similar questions about operator precedences in Java.

**First one:**

```
int X = 10;
System.out.println(X++ * ++X * X++); //it prints 1440
```

According to [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):
postfix (expr++, expr--) operators have higher precedence than prefix (++expr, --expr)

So, I suppose that evaluation order:

```
1) first postfix operator: X++ 
   1.a) X++ "replaced" by 10
   1.b) X incremented by one: 10+1=11
   At this step it should look like:  System.out.println(10 * ++X * X++), X = 11;

2) second POSTfix operator: X++ 
   2.a) X++ "replaced" by 11
   2.b) X incremented by one: 11+1=12
   At this step it should look like:  System.out.println(10 * ++X * 11), X = 12;

3) prefix operator: ++X
   3.a) X incremented by one: 12+1=13
   3.b) ++X "replaced" by 13
   At this step it should look like:  System.out.println(10 * 13 * 11), X = 13;

4) evaluating 10*13 = 130, 130*11 = 1430.
```

But Java seems to ignore PRE/POST ordering and puts them on one level. So the real order:

```
 X++ -> ++X -> X++
```

what causes the answer to be (10 * 12 * 12) = 1440.

**Second one:**

[Example from  this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489489/why-is-this-java-operator-precedence-being-ignored-here)

```
    int a=1, b=2;             
    a = b + a++;
```

Part of accepted answer:
"By the time of assignment, `++` has already incremented the value of `a` to `2` (because of precedence), so `=` overwrites that incremented value."

OK, let's look step-by-step:

```
 1) replacing "b" with 2
 2) replacing "a++" with 1
 3) incrementing "a" by 1 -> at this point a==2
 4) evaluating 2+1 = 3
 5) overwriting incremented value of "a" with 3
```

Seems everything is fine.
But let's make a little change in that code (replace "=" with "+=")

```
    a += b + a++;
```

steps 1-4 should be same as above.
so, after step 4 we have something like that:

```
    a += 3;
```

where `a==2`

And then I think: OK, `a = 2+3`, so `a` should be `5`. BUT the answer is only `4`

I'm really confused. I already spent couple of hours but still can't understand where I am wrong.

P.S. I know, that I shouldn't use this "style" in real applications. I just want to understand what is wrong in my thoughts.

Comment: No, expressions are evaluated left to right and * has higher precedence. So you need to swap 2 and 3 in your first analysis. And a+= is replaced with a=a+.

Comment: @assylias: `*` has higher precedence than what?  I think that part is misleading.  But it is true that expressions are *evaluated* left to right and that that explains everything (see my answer).

Comment: Sorry lower, than pre/post increment - meaning that the operands of the multiplication are evaluated first, from left to right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The confusion stems from the fact that the operands are *evaluated* from left to right.  **This is done first, before any attention is paid to operator precedence/order of operations**.

This behavior is specified in [**JLS 15.7.2. Evaluate Operands before Operation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html)

So `X++ * ++X * X++` is first evaluated as `10 * 12 * 12` which yields, as you saw, 1440.

To convince yourself of this, consider the following:

```
X = 10; System.out.println(X++ * ++X);
X = 10; System.out.println(++X * X++);
```

If `X++` were done first, then `++X` second, then multiplication, both should print the same number.

But they do not:

```
X = 10; System.out.println(X++ * ++X); // 120
X = 10; System.out.println(++X * X++); // 121
```

So how does this make sense?  Well if we realize that operands are evaluated from left to right, then it makes perfect sense.

```
X = 10; System.out.println(X++ * ++X); // 120 (10 * 12)
X = 10; System.out.println(++X * X++); // 121 (11 * 11)
```

The first line looks like

```
X++       * ++X
10 (X=11) * (X=12) 12
10        * 12 = 120
```

and the second

```
++X       * X++
(X=11) 11 * 11 (X=12)
11        * 11 = 121
```

---

### So why are prefix and postfix increment/decrement operators in the table?

It is true that increment and decrement must be *performed* before multiplication.  But what that is saying is that:

```
Y = A * B++

// Should be interpreted as
Y = A * (B++)

// and not
Y = (A * B)++
```

Just as

```
Y = A + B * C

// Should be interpreted as
Y = A + (B * C)

// and not
Y = (A + B) * C
```

It remains that the order of the *evaluation* of the operands occurs left-to-right.

---

### If you're still not conviced:

Consider the following program:

```
class Test
{
    public static int a(){ System.out.println("a"); return 2; }
    public static int b(){ System.out.println("b"); return 3; }
    public static int c(){ System.out.println("c"); return 4; }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(a() + b() * c());
        // Lets make it even more explicit
        System.out.println(a() + (b() * c()));
    }
}
```

If the arguments were *evaluated* at the time they were needed, either `b` or `c` would come first, the other next, and lastly `a`.  However, the program outputs:

```
a
b
c
14
a
b
c
14
```

Because, regardless of the order that they're needed and used in the equation, they're still *evaluated* left to right.

Helpful reading:

- [What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java)
- [a += a++ * a++ * a++ in Java. How does it get evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369393/a-a-a-a-in-java-how-does-it-get-evaluated?rq=1)
- [Appendix A: Operator Precedence in Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

Comment: oh, I found document from Princeton and coded almost the same code. So, we always move from left to right. And **ONLY** if we have two operators share same operand - we look at the Precedence Order Table.

Comment: Not really.  Think of it as a two step process.  First we *evaluate* the operands, from left to right.  Then we use the operators, as determined by the table, to compute the result.

Comment: This may help: [JLS 15.7.2. Evaluate Operands before Operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html)

Comment: nope. "The Java programming language guarantees that **every operand of an operator** appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed." `int arr[] = null;int tmp = 5 * 3 / 0 / arr[0];` - I have `/ by zero` exception, not `NullPointerException`. That is, we have operator `*` - we know both operands - we evaluate it, now we have `15 / 0 / arr[0]`. Next operator `/` - we know both operands, evaluate them and boom - `/ by zero` exception.

Comment: Nope what?  And why are you quoting from the link, I read it, *I pasted it*.

Comment: I understood your comment as "first we evaluate ALL operands, then we use the operators". If you didn't mean that - my "nope" is wrong, I'm sorry.

Comment: One thing I still have trouble understanding is that if operands are evaluated from left to right, "does it matter" that `x++` has a higher precedence than `++x`. In other words, can I concoct an expression where the result would be different if the precedences were reversed?

Comment: @jedwards - This is the best and amazing explanation I have ever read. Cleared the confusion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In short,

Precedence is like preparing the expression to be calculated by putting parentheses. Evaluation comes next from left to right considering each pair of parentheses as a separate operation.

For example,if `i=2` then `i+i++` becomes `i+(i++)` after precedence and evaluates to `2+2 = 4`.
However, `i+++i` becomes `(i++)+i` and evaluates to `2+3 = 5`.

Same to `i+(i=5)` which evaluates to `2+5 = 7`.

In fact the postfix operators do have higher precedence than prefix operators. For example, `i+++++i` becomes `((i++)++)+i` after precedence which gives a compile error (the second postfix operator needs a variable to operate on but a value is found instead!). If both postfix and prefix operators had had equal precedence then the expression would have become `(i++)+(++i)` and evaluates to `2+4 = 6`.

If you need more explanation you can compile and run the following code and inspect the examples printed at the output.

```
public class TestPrecedence {
    public static void main(String[] str) {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i = " + i + "\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i++ = " + i++ + "\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("++i = " + ++i + "\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i++i = (i++)i TestPrecedence.java:8: error: ')' expected\n"+
                                  "              i++i\n"+
                                  "                 ^\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i+-i = i+(-i) = " + (i+-i) + "\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("++i++ = ++(i++) TestPrecedence.java:12: error: unexpected type\n"+
                                  "                ++i++ \n"+
                                  "                   ^\n"+
                                  "                required: variable\n"+
                                  "                found:    value\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i+++++i = ((i++)++)+i TestPrecedence.java:17: error: unexpected type\n"+
                                  "                      i+++++i\n"+
                                  "                       ^\n"+
                                  "                      required: variable\n"+
                                  "                      found:    value\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i++ + ++i = " + (i++ + ++i) + "\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i+(i=3) = " + (i+(i=3)) + " evaluates left to right\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i+i++ precedence yields i+(i++) evaluates to 2+2 = " + (i+i++) + "\n");
        i = 2; System.out.println("i+++i precedence yields (i++)+i evaluates to 2+3 = " + (i+++i) + "\n");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why its 1440 is because

1. x is set to 10 i.e 1st term is FIXED(overall equation 10  *)
2. x is incremented by 1,x =11 now
3. x is pre-incremented by 1 x=12 and second term FIXED now (overall equation 10 * 12 *)
4. now x is set to 12 and third term FIXED(overall equation 10 * 12 *12)
5. x is increment now but is in this case not used for evaluation,

in short a term is FIXED when variable occurs which in this case is X

2nd case:
I'm not sure but I guess can be broken as,

1. `a=b+a`
2. `a++`

which I think is what is happening.

Comment: It's clear. But look at the [table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). **prefix** has lower precedence than **postfix**. So why is it evaluated _before_ last postfix? That's the main problem for me.

Comment: this may be wrong,but just a guess,is because of left to right evaluation in java..say its 2 *3 *5 in java, i think it straightaway doesnt multiply it to 30 it does 2*3=6 1st and den multiplies it by 5

Answer (score 0):

First step

```
1) first postfix operator: X++ 
   1.a) X++ "replaced" by 10
   1.b) X incremented by one: 10+1=11
   At this step it should look like:  System.out.println(10 * ++X * X++), X = 11;

2) prefix operator: ++X
   2.a) X "replaced" by 11
   2.b) X incremented by one: 11+1=12
   At this step it should look like:  System.out.println(10 * 12 * X++), X = 12;

3) second POSTfix operator: X++
   3.a) X "replaced" by 12
   3.b) X incremented by one: 12+1=13
   At this step it should look like:  System.out.println(10 * 12 * 12),  X = 13;
```

This prints `10 * 12 * 12 = 1440`

**This is the bytecode for the first step**

```
 1. bipush 10
 2. istore_0
 3. getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 4. iload_0
 5. iinc 0 1
 6. iinc 0 1
 7. iload_0
 8. imul
 9. iload_0
10. iinc 0 1
11. imul
12. invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
13. return
```

This do the following:

```
 1. Push 10 to the stack
 2. Pop 10 from the stack to X variable
 3. Push X variable value (10) to the stack
 5. Increment local variable X (11)
 6. Increment local variable X (12)
 7. Push X variable value (12) to the stack
 8. Multiply top and subtop (10*12) Now Top = 120 
 9. Push X variable value (12) to the stack
10. Increment local variable X (13)
11. Multiply top and subtop (120*12) Now Top = 1440
```

Notice than the last increment (10.) is done after the push of X to the stack

Comment: Its now even worse, `*` *doesn't* have higher precedence -- see the link in the post.

Comment: @jedwards But expression are evaluated left to right, the prefix `++` is evaluated first, and then the second postfix `++`. You are right about the precedence.

Comment: @jedwards please evaluate my new answer

Comment: @omainegra can you please keep the earlier explanation as well?

Answer (score 0):

For the second one ->

```
int a=1, b=2;             
a += b + a++;
```

Compiler will convert it to

```
 a = a + b + a++;
```

Then apply your logic and you will find the reason why a is 4.