# If post-increment/decrement has precedence over pre-increment/decrement, then why is this expression evaluated like so:

Tags: java, operator-precedence

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;
        int y = ++x * 5 * x--;
        System.out.println("x is " + x);
        System.out.println("y is " + y);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
x is 3
y is 80
```

But using the rule that post-operators take precedence over pre-operators, shouldn't it be like this:

```
y = ++x * 5 * 3 (x is 2)
y = 3 * 5 * 3 (x is 3)
y = 45
```

Instead, this code is acting as if it just evaluated the expression from left-to-right, evaluating the pre-increment before the post-decrement.  Why?

Comment: I tend to think of precedence as being like adding brackets. The code you've shown here doesn't demonstrate precedence between those operators. It's effectively ((++x) * 5) * (x--), and for each binary operator, the LHS is evaluated first.

Comment: *using the rule that post-operators take precedence over pre-operators*, no there is no such rule. The only rule, which explains the output is that of left-to-right evaluation of each expression.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you!  Now I get it.

Comment: @Tunaki: It's somewhat confusing that the Java tutorial *does* have that precedence: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html It's a poorly worded page IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet you should turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.  The people who have answered so far didn't bother to explain the meaning of operator precedence.

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés: I started to, but the question was closed before I could submit.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, yeah, that's unfortunate.  Ok, thanks anyway

Comment: You were probably reading the OCA textbook from Boyarsky because I stumbled upon the exact same question! Turns out, after searching the web a lil, that "There is no explicit operator precedence table in the Java Language Specification. Different tables on the web and in textbooks disagree in some minor ways." link: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/  I do trust Priceton, but  I still have some doubts :) I would reopen this question but I don't have privileges :)

Comment: @Tunaki:"using the rule that post-operators take precedence over pre-operators, no there is no such rule." - there is a rule as defined in the table 'Operator Precedence' https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html. There is a clear explanation of this rule given by Merka in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489489/why-is-this-java-operator-precedence-being-ignored-here.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: "It's a poorly worded page IMO" - if you say so to mean the same thing like Tunaki then see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

```
int y = ++x * 5 * x--;

++x => Increase then evaluate => x == 4
x-- => Evaluate then decrease
```

So actually it looks like this:

```
int y = 4 * 5 * 4; // == 80
```

and because of the decrement operator, your `x` is `3` at the end.

Comment: You're doing the pre-increment before the post-decrement.  So, what do people mean when they say that post-operators have higher precedence than pre-operators?

Comment: @JohnPeterThompsonGarcés they mean that post-operators "bind tighter" than pre-operators, so that in determining which operators _that apply to the same operands_ they apply first. Eg in `--x++` the `++` binds tighter and the expression is effectively `--(x++)` (though it doesn't compile). In your example the operands are different (though they are both written as `x`, they represent potentially different values) so the precedence between pre- and post- operators is not significant.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is `y = ++x * 5 * 3 (x is 2)` its not `(4)*5*3` its `(4)*5*4`. Pemdas my friend

```
    int x = 3;
    int y = ++x * 5 * x--;  //x becomes 4 , then its 4*5*4 =80 = y
    System.out.println("x is " + x); // x-- comes into affect and x = 3
    System.out.println("y is " + y);  // y = 80
```

Although x-- is being evaluated before x++ and everything else. It changes the value of x after the whole expression is evaluated. Unlike ++x when it get evaluated it changes the value of x immediately.

Comment: You haven't really explained that at all, to my mind...

Comment: @JonSkeet better, sorry for the lack of evaluation ?

Comment: Not really, you've missed the point of the question - which was the OP stating that post-operators are meant to have higher precedence than pre-operators (as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html for example) - your answer doesn't address that at all.